# How to connect windbg and virtualbox

Tags: windbg, virtualbox

> How to connect windows debugger and other dev tools on your host machine to windows xp on oracle virtualbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to install WinDbg on both machines and then debug remotely,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh451173(v=vs.85).aspx